# Find out if user name exists

Tags: bash, unix, shell

How can I find out, in a shell script, whether a given user name exists on the current system?

---

`/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` are incomplete. Consider OS X's Directory Services, or Linux with Likewise Active Directory integration.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

One of the most basic tools to be used for that is probably `id`.

```
#!/bin/bash
if id "$1" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        echo "user exists"
else
        echo "user does not exist"
fi
```

Which produces

```
$ ./userexists root
user exists
$ ./userexists alice
user does not exist
$ ./userexists
user does not exist
```

Comment: You don't need the backquotes here -- just use `if id -u "$1" >/dev/null 2>&1; then` ...

Comment: @Gordon absolutely right of course. Thanks :)

Comment: "-u" also seems unnecessary

Comment: Wha's if I needed only `if` with negative result checker?

Comment: `id -u $1 1>/dev/null 2>&1; echo $?` can be used for pipe

Comment: On older Solaris it may be worthwhile to use `id` located at `/usr/xpg4/bin/id` rather than `/usr/bin/id`.

Comment: So in general a stdout is true and stderr is false?

Comment: @wordsforthewise Processes have "exit codes" they return upon termination - zero for success, non-zero for failure. This is independent from their output on stdout and stderr.

Comment: @wordsforthewise: No. `stdout` and `stderr` are just distinct _outputs_. And there's a _convention_, that virtually all tools follow, to use `stdout` to print regular messages and `stderr` to print error messages. So when you use `1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null` (or any of its shortcuts like `>/dev/null 2>&1` or `&>/dev/null`), you're simply redirecting _both_ outputs to `/dev/null` (ie, discarding them)

Comment: @YuraShinkarev: use `!` to invert the check: `if ! id "$1"; then echo "no such user"; fi`

Answer (score 27):

**getent**

This command is designed to gather entries for the databases that can be backed by /etc files and various remote services like LDAP, AD, NIS/Yellow Pages, DNS and the likes.

To figure out if a username is known by one of the password naming services, simply run:

```
getent passwd username
```

This works also with group, hosts and others, depending on the OS and implementation.

Comment: While Solaris and Linux, and more recently also most BSDs have `getent`, there is no `getent` on Mac OS X

Comment: Indeed, I missed Mac OS/X is missing getent.

Comment: Nevertheless it's quite useful on the systems it supports.

Comment: getent is nice because you can query multiple usernames where id only supports a single username.

Answer (score 7):

### `finger`

Parse the output of `finger -m <username>`. No error code if no user was found, unfortunately, but if not found, error output will be written. No drawbacks so far.

```
finger -ms <username> 2>&1 1>/dev/null | wc -l
```

Will print `0` if user is found (because there's no error output), larger numbers otherwise.

### `chown`

Run (as any user, surprisingly):

```
T=$( mktemp -t foo.XXX ) ; chown <username> $T
```

If it fails as `root`, the account name is invalid.

If it fails as non-`root` user, parse the possibly localized output for *Operation not permitted* or *invalid user* (or equivalents). Set `LANG` beforehand to do this reliably.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that you would want to rely on `/etc/passwd` and similar (e.g. `/etc/shadow` for Shadow-based systems; on an off-topic side-note, some similar systems might use `/etc/master.passwd` or other such files).

The `/etc/passwd` is typically treated as the absolute authoritative decision on whether a user exists or not.  If you use any of the other methods described on this page, and if those other methods point to an existing user but `/etc/passwd` does not, then I would say that the user does not properly exist on the system, by definition of the most common standard that software would likely rely on.

That said, I'll throw in another way to add to the mix of some other options that could be used.

`ls -l /home | grep ^customUserName$<BR>
echo $?`

Clearly, replace "customuserName" with the name of the user you want to check for.  Replace /home with /users if that is what your system uses.  This might not find all users in /etc/passwd if no home directory was made for the particular user, which could occur if you simply imported users (that is, lines of text into /etc/passwd) and if home directories don't get made unless/until a person logs in.

Comment: I don't get why you state a user who has no entry in the /etc/password file but is reported to be valid by either `id` or `getent` does not "properly" exist on the system, especially when the OP is clearly stating naming services are to be considered.