# How to count the approximate number of Intel-compatible binaries/programs on a computer running OS X Lion, and time that count?

Tags: osx-lion, cpu-architecture

For an *approximate* count — and to get an idea of the time taken to count — I began with a multi-line command that could run in tcsh.

I'm not a plumbing expert, so I invite answers that are better than the earliest one given by me below.

### Notes

To keep the walk not excessively time-consuming, I'd like to:

- walk just a few hierarchies that are most likely to contain binaries
- not begin the walk at / root.

I'm as interested in the time taken to count, as the approximate count.

### References

[arch(3) Mac OS X Developer Tools Manual Page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man3/arch.3.html)

[lipo(1) Mac OS X Manual Page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/lipo.1.html)

Comment: I had to `2>/dev/null` before the pipe to prevent a ton of crap from being printed.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I edited my question to make clear that I manually count the number of lines of output (I don't know whether this can be plumbed). Did you use tcsh?

Comment: Consider posting your approach as an answer, like I did e.g. [here](http://superuser.com/questions/336275/find-out-if-user-name-exists).

Comment: I'm playing around with it right now, but no, I use bash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the following in `bash`, keeping the overall approach (using `lipo`) the same:

> `time find ${PATH//:/ } /Applications /Developer /Library /System ~/Applications -type f -exec lipo -info '{}' ';' 2>/dev/null | grep -E "(x86_64|i.86|pent)" | tee binaries.txt | wc -l`

It will create a file, `binaries.txt` with the list of results, and print the number of results, as well as the `time` results, to standard output.

I shortened the `man 3 arch` based `grep` expression, removed the `i860` entry, and used `$PATH` instead of a hardcoded list of Unix binary locations. I also removed the `-perm` primary from `find`, as it's a heuristic that might miss binaries only executable for specific users.

Comment: To be honest, it's a whole lot faster *with* the `-perm` primary :-/

Comment: Seems I get a whole lot of false positives, if you don't want to find libraries, this way (it's still running :-) ).

Comment: Without permissions filter: `9531`. With permissions filter: `8394`. It takes more than ten times as long without on my system though.

Comment: Daniel, you're amazing. Thanks! It's certainly time-consuming, here more than twenty minutes for my [earlier untidy approach](http://superuser.com/a/384260/84988) to complete.

Answer (score 2):

In `tcsh`:

```
sh
uname -v && date &&\
2>/dev/null find /opt/X11/bin /opt/local/bin /opt/local/sbin \
/bin /sbin /usr/X11/bin /usr/bin /usr/local/bin /usr/sbin \
/Applications /Developer /Library /System ~/Applications \
-type f -perm +111 -exec lipo -info '{}' ';' | grep -E \
"(i386|x86_64|i860|i486|i486SX|pentium|i586|pentpro|i686|pentIIm3|pentIIm5|pentium4)" &&\
date && exit
```

The number of lines of output can be counted in a text editor such as TextWrangler. Subtract from the beginning the few lines up to and including the date and time, subtract from the end the two lines that include the date and time, that leaves an approximate figure.

If you wonder why the grep is for any of twelve architectures (not two): it's to consider **all** currently known architectures where the description, in the man page for arch, includes *Intel*. Finding anything other than i386 or x86_64 may be rare or unknown at the moment, but I'd like the answers to this question to stand the test of time, to be not limited to those two.

As an answer, this is far from ideal …

Comment: `i860`? It has a *different instruction set*...

Comment: Most architecture and instruction set stuff is way beyond me, to be honest. I recognise *Pentium* as something that sounds outdated. I have no idea whether anyone might try Darwin 11 on i860 … and so on. Parts of this answer are probably **very** far from ideal!

Comment: Is lipo the best tool for this sort of thing? Inspiration for the lipo approach is given around [http://www.wuala.com/grahamperrin/public/2011/07/12/ppc-lister](http://www.wuala.com/grahamperrin/public/2011/07/12/ppc-lister). System Information.app is in many ways user-friendly, and will list applications quickly, but it doesn't provide detail of the type that we get from `lipo`.

Comment: I'm not sure the `Non-fat` expression (on the linked page) is correct. Mac OS (classic) had fat binaries as well, working on both 68k and PPC. Not sure what the output there is though.

Answer (score 2):

### A little beyond the opening question

Sill experimenting, here's a variation on the accepted answer from Daniel:

```
date && sw_vers && uname -a && touch /Users/Shared/binaries.log && bash 
open /Users/Shared/binaries.log && time find ${PATH//:/ } \
/Applications /Developer /Library /System ~/Applications \
-type f -exec lipo -info '{}' ';' 2>/dev/null \
| grep -E "(x86_64|i.86|pent)" | tee /Users/Shared/binaries.log \
| wc -l && exit
```

It uses a shared area to write the file, with a name ending in `.log`, and should open the .log in Console. Also the Terminal window will show the date and time, system version and build — things that I like to keep a note of.

It does not bring the log window to foreground if other windows of Console are open, and does not bring Terminal to foreground at completion.

On some systems the walk may be very time-consuming.

### For a faster run

We can use the `-perm` primary of `find` —

```
date && sw_vers && uname -a && touch /Users/Shared/binaries.log && bash 
open /Users/Shared/binaries.log && time find ${PATH//:/ } \
/Applications /Developer /Library /System ~/Applications \
-perm +111 -type f -exec lipo -info '{}' ';' 2>/dev/null \
| grep -E "(x86_64|i.86|pent)" | tee /Users/Shared/binaries.log \
| wc -l && exit
```

— but as [Daniel commented](https://superuser.com/a/384255/84988), this might miss binaries that are only executable for specific users.