# Check if user exists using id (linux)

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

I see a lot of examples about check if user exists in *nix system using id

- [Find out if user name exists](https://superuser.com/questions/336275/find-out-if-user-name-exists)
- [Check Whether a User Exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810684/check-whether-a-user-exists)

For test my code i've create a simple code and after check and verify work I've copied to develop script

checkuser.sh

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function checkUser() {
  if id "$USER" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        echo "user exists"
  else
        echo "user does not exist"
  fi
}

USER=$4
checkUser
```

Test code

```
sudo local/checkuser.sh misitio test 7.3 abkrim /home/abkrim/Sites/ 
abkrim.EXISTS
user exists
```

But when copy in my script not work

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [ $EUID != 0 ]; then
    sudo "$0" "$@"
    exit $?
fi

SITE=$1
PHP=$3
USER=$4
NGINX=/etc/nginx/
FPM=/etc/php/${PHP}/fpm/pool.d/
PATH=$5
checkUser
```

Test code

```bsh
sudo local/deploy_site.sh misitio test 7.3 abkrim /home/abkrim/Sites/                                                         
abkrim
user does not exist
```

Comment: Did you read all the comments in the examples that you copied from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PATH` is in the environment, it is [special](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)). After your script does `PATH=$5`, it's no longer able to find the `id` executable; therefore this

```
id "$USER" >/dev/null 2>&1
```

silently fails.

You probably do not want to overwrite `PATH`. You probably want [your variables in lower case](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42849/108618).

However if you *really* want to overwrite `PATH`, then you should later use full path to any executable that shouldn't depend on the new ("custom") `PATH`. E.g. `/usr/bin/id`.

Comment: Thanks you. A mistake wiuth PATH var.. Usually program in PHP and JS and despite with bash.